We have a continuous function $f:\mathbb R\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ and ...
The function is : $$f(x)=3x^2+\int_0^x \left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^t f(x-t)dt$$ Here my question is can we say $f(0)=0$:$$f(0)=3(0)^2+\int_0^0 \left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^t f(-t) dt$$ but the question is can we write this step as $f(0)=0$ ? hence we can also find $f(x)$ because we can apply KING'S property of integration i.e. $$\int_0^a f(x) dx = \int_0^a f(a-x)dx$$ to the integral making it $$\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^x\int_0^x (e^t)f(t) dt$$ and then solve the integral by integration by parts , is this a way to solve it ? Here 't' being a parameter for integration

What do you mean when you say that$$f(x)=3x^2+\int_0^x\left(\frac1e\right)^xf(x-t),\mathrm dt?$$How does this define $f$?

f(x) is a continuous function depending on the variable 'x' and the expression is how f(x) is represented in terms of x

Don't you really see that you are defining $f$ using $f$ itself? Isn't there a problem for you? If it's not, please tell me what if $f(1)$.

@JoséCarlosSantos I think OP is asking us to solve this integral equation for $f$.

If $f$ is continuous at $0$ you can prove that necessarily $f(0)=0$. If this is what you're asking (the question is not clear) I can write an answer

Yes thank you  Lavender sorry for the misunderstanding @JoséCarlosSantos. Also if anyone can explain that is there an error here ? And  that what is the difference  between f(t) and f(x) ?

It is trivial that any function that satisfies your first equation (an integral equation) must satisfy $f(0)=0,.$ How else would you write this? How you conclude that $f(t)=3t^2$ goes beyond my comprehension. If this were true you would have
$$
3x^2=3x^3+\int_0^x\left(\frac1e\right)^t3(x-t)^2,dt,
$$
or
$$
0=\int_0^x\left(\frac1e\right)^t3(x-t)^2,dt
$$
which is obviously wrong.

@KurtG I think you might have substituted x=0 , so wouldn't  you substitute it in the upper limit of the given integral making it zero ? Because that's what I did to get f(0) =0

@Naman what Kurt means is that from this it follows that $f(t)=3t^2$ precisely when $t=0$. This doesn't tell you that $f(t)=3t^2$ in general

Sorry I am getting confused here I am very new to calculus (in high school) , so my question here is what does 't' mean here in the integral equation ?

$t$ is the variable you are integrating with respect to.

Right but what does  f(x-t) mean , am I right to think that x is taken as a constant in the integral and that t as you said is our parameter  , also sorry but one last question is it correct that they mentioned f(x-t) and not something like g(x-t)[some other function]?

It does serve well to think of $x$ here as constant. The integral equation you gave can be thought of as one separate equation for each value of $x$. I'm not sure what you mean with your last question.

You mentioned t is a parameter but what does f(x-t) men because how can a function can have two variables ?

It doesn't. x-t is one number and is the input to the function.

Right but both x and t are variables ? and also what does a parameter do exactly like in this integral equation?

If you don't know what $f(x-t)$ in that integral equations means how did you know what that KING'S property means?

I know the properties of integration and also what f(x-t) means it means that f is a function of x-t but my question is how is it depending on 2 variables x and t in the integral yes we take x as constant but is t just an variable that we use in the integration and just for the integration part we take t in place of x ? And so are f(x) and f(t) the same ? And if yes then can we  get f(t) = 3t² ?

Suppose $f$ is continuous and satisfies the integral equation you give.
The first question we should ask before proceeding any further to deduce properties of $f$ is "does this uniquely determine $f$?" Rearranging the integral equation, we can try to answer this:

Use King's to obtain $$f(x)=3x^2+e^{-x}\int_0^xe^{t}f(t)\mathrm{d}t\ \ \ \ (*)$$
Since the RHS is differentiable by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $f$ must also be. Also, it is clear that $f(0)=0$, giving us: $$f'(x)=6x+f(x)-e^{-x}\int_0^xe^{t}f(t)\mathrm dt$$
We can substitute $(*)$ to remove the nasty integral expression:$$f'(x)=6x+f(x)-f(x)+3x^2$$
We then have $f(x)=3x^2+x^3+C$; since the original equation nicely gives us the initial value $f(0)=0$, it follows that $f$ is uniquely determined, and is equal to $3x^2+x^3$.


It should also be checked that $f(x)=3x^2+x^3$ does satisfy the integral equation.

Right but one question here but isn't the derivative of a definite integral zero ?

@Naman we are differentiating with respect to one of the integral bounds, so no.

@Naman $\int_0^x f(t)\mathrm dt$ happens to be a function of $x$, and (provided $f$ is continuous) a differentiable one too
